# How does author derives $\cos \theta = \frac{dx}{ds} \qquad \sin\theta = \frac{dy }{ds}, $?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

In the book of *Dynamics* by Horace Lamb, at page 103, is it given

> that for a motion on a smooth curve, the equation of motion is given
>   by  $$mv \frac{dv }{ ds} = -mg \sin \theta  \qquad \frac{ mv^2 }{r} =
>  -mg \cos\theta + R, $$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the surface normal and vertical direction, and $R$ is the "pressure" exerted by
>   the curve.
>
> [...]
>
> Then, we have  $$\cos \theta = \frac{dx}{ds} \qquad \sin\theta =
>  \frac{dy  }{ds},  $$ where $s$ is length of the path taken over the
>   surface, and $x,y$ are usual cartesian coordinates as $y$ is taken as
>   upward.

However, I cannot understand how does the author derives the latter equations between $\theta$ and the derivatives of $x,y$ wrt $s$.

Comment: This seems like a math question, but https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250 describes why the migration to Math SE failed and the post was closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a small segment of the curve, and approximate this segment with a straight line $\Delta s$. Then Pythagoras' theorem gives you

$$ \Delta s^2 = \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2 $$

According to basic trigonometry:

$$ \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta s} = \cos\, \alpha,\;\; \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta s} = \sin\, \alpha,  $$

where $\alpha$ is the angle between $\Delta s$ and $\Delta x$. In the limit the same equations hold for $\dfrac{dx}{ds}$ and $\dfrac{dy}{ds}$.

I don't understand the definition of $\theta$ in the question, but either it can be identified with the angle $\alpha$, or more unlikely, the book is wrong.

Comment: Generally the angle when looking at $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta s}$ is different than when looking at $\frac{\text d x}{\text d s}$

Comment: Yes. But if $x=x(s)$ is a continuous function, the angle difference can be made arbitrarily small by choosing a sufficiently small $\Delta s$.

Comment: Typically $\Delta$ is used for "larger" values, and $\text d$ is used for infinitesimal values as we take the $\Delta$ value to $0$. So if you write $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta s}=\cos\alpha$, then as you take the $\Delta$ values to $0$, the angle between $\Delta x$ and $\Delta s$ will change during this process. The angle will approach some value.

Comment: That is exactly my point.

Comment: It's somewhat analagous to how in introductory calculus how the slope of the secant line approaches the slope of the tangent line. $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=m$ for the slope of the secant line. Then you take the $\Delta$ quantities $0$, and $m$ approaches a value generally different from the original $m$. The same thing is happening here. Just because the angle between $\Delta x$ and $\Delta s$ is $\alpha$ does not mean that it stays this way. Therefore, if you write  $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta s}=\cos\alpha$, you should note that $\alpha$ changes as you take the limit to get to $\frac{dx}{ds}$

Comment: I thought I covered all that by mentioning "In the limit". But please feel free to edit my answer if you think more clarification of introductory calculus is needed to make it understandable.

Comment: Nah I'm probably being picky. Good answer. Hopefully it is "analytic" enough for the OP. I tried giving them the general idea of this in the comments, but they seemed dissatisfied.